# Highcharts Toggle Stacking for Multi-Axis Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to toggle stacking for a multi-axis chart, but it seems I can only toggle one series at a time.

Does anyone know how to solve this?  Here is a link to the jsfiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/kz7wbykx/

```js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo:'container',
        defaultSeriesType:'column',
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'#ccc',
        marginLeft:110,
        marginRight:50,
        backgroundColor:'#eee',
        plotBackgroundColor:'#fff',
    },
    title:{
        text:'Chart Title'
    },
    legend:{
                                     
    },
    tooltip:{
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking:'normal',
            fillColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
        },
    },
    xAxis:{
        lineColor:'#999',
        lineWidth:1,
        tickColor:'#666',
        tickLength:3,
        title:{
            text:'X Axis Title'
        }
    },
    yAxis:{
        lineColor:'#999',
        lineWidth:1,
        tickColor:'#666',
        tickWidth:1,
        tickLength:3,
        gridLineColor:'#ddd',
        title:{
            text:'Y Axis Title',
            rotation:0,
            margin:50,
        }
    },
    series: [{
        stack: 1,
        name:'Series 1 Name',
        data: [5,8,7,4,6]
    },{
      stack: 1,
        name:'Series 2 Name',
        data: [2,3,6,5,7]
    },{
      stack: 1,
        name:'Series 3 Name',
        data: [1,4,6,8,9]
    }]
},function(chart){
    $('button').click(function(){
      chart.series[0].options.stack = +!chart.series[0].options.stack;
        chart.series[1].options.stack = +!chart.series[1].options.stack;
        //chart.series[2].options.stack = +!chart.series[2].options.stack;
        chart.series[0].hide();
        chart.series[1].hide();
        chart.series[2].hide();
        chart.series[0].show();
        chart.series[1].show();
        chart.series[2].show();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button>toggle stacking</button>
```

Comment: I think that the best idea is to use Series.update method in your case:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/kz7wbykx/1/

Comment: You're absolutely correct!  thank you!

Comment: Happy to read that my solution worked for you. :) I have posted it as an answer.

Comment: Accepted.  Cheers!

Comment: My chart has 6 columns.  Can you create a working example with 6 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use Series.update() method in case of changing stack of your series. Here you can find information about this method: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update

```
  $('button').click(function() {
    chart.series[0].update({
      stack: chart.series[0].options.stack == '1' ? '0' : '1'
    }, false);
    chart.series[1].update({
      stack: chart.series[1].options.stack == '1' ? '2' : '1'
    }, false);
    chart.redraw();
  })
```

Here you can see an example how your chart may work using Series.update():
http://fiddle.jshell.net/kz7wbykx/1/

Regards,

Comment: That seems to work for 3 columns, but if I add another column, two of the columns stay stacked.  http://fiddle.jshell.net/baberuth22/9w2md7t3/

Comment: I figured it out.  The stack value is like the stack number, not boolean true / false.  http://fiddle.jshell.net/baberuth22/Lrq4e9j5/